# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'foreign_type' for PaperTrail::VersionAssociation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

I am migrating my application from Rails4.2.8 to Rails5.2.3, updated paper-trail gem version '7.1.2' to '10.3.1'.I am using Rspec - 3.8.2. Everything worked fine but my specs are failing for models which used 'has_paper_trail' macro.

Tried looking into my codes as well as gem repo, didn't found such attribute anywhere.

Found some similar issue but it didn't helped.
https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/455

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError:unknown attribute 'foreign_type' for PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.`

Comment: "updated paper-trail gem version 7 to 10" .. I strongly recommend updating one major version at a time. Update 7 to 8, make sure all tests pass, make sure all deprecation warnings are fixed, then update 8 to 9, etc.

Comment: Am also migrating and seeing this. Am going from Rails 5.3 -> 6.0.1, and paper_trail was already on 10.3.1.

Comment: also dealing with this upgrading a very old app. Might just remove paper trail

Answer (score 7):

You need to add column `foreign_type` into `version_associations` tables after upgrading gem `paper_trail`.

Run `rails g paper_trail_association_tracking:add_foreign_type_to_version_associations` and then migrate your database.

These changes were done in gem `paper_trail-association_tracking` which is one of the dependencies for `paper_trail` gem.

Ref: [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)